# Ubuntu 16.04 not showing battery indicator

Tags: power-management, indicator, battery, charging

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my lenovo yoga 300 laptop. However, it is not showing battery indicator.

In the setting>power, there also no battery option is available. It does not show any indication when battery is low and it will suddenly turn off when battery goes to 0%.

[image]

Comment: Press `Super` and type `dconf`, open the program. Follow the path *com>canonical>unity-greeter* and check the list where it says *indicators*, is  `'com.canonical.indicator.power'` present?

Comment: That does not look like power saving options in my xenial install, did you add a third party repository?

Comment: in indicator has following   ug-accessibility, com.canonical.indicator.keyboard, com.canonical.indicator.session, com.canonical.indicator.datetime, com.canonical.indicator.power, com.canonical.indicator.sound, application

Comment: I main problem is that without any low battery indication it turns off when battery goes low.

Comment: Can you verify if upower can detect batteries and show statistics? (run 'upower' in terminal, if not applicable then as root (sudo))

Answer (score 0):

if you need it desperately then, just re-install ubuntu-desktop

to remove :

sudo apt-get autoremove ubuntu-desktop

and to again install it:

sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop